# Android ListView doesn't cooperate

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I've been studying Android ListViews recently and I'm having some issues. I looked at a few tutorials and got the most basic ListViews working just fine. But now I would like to make a ListView that displays a series of objects. I thought I was doing everything correct. My code does not produce any errors but the List I wish to create does not display at all. Obviously, I'm not sure why.

The Purpose of this application is to compile a list of weather stations and airports and display information (ex. names, ID#, coordinates, etc) - all of which is parsed from an XML document and contained in an Arraylist(Built by a separate class with proper constructors/getters/setters). Basically I get a list of stations then - then from that list - a list of station names set to an Adapter. My ListView should display only the names of each station but to no avail.

I've tested my Parser and My Arrays. It all works, just nothing displays. According to all the tutorials my logic should be correct down to my Adapter. Does anyone have any suggestions? I feel like I'm exhausting all solutions. My code is posted below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//local variables
    String station_id;
    String state;
    String station_name;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    String html_url;

//ArrayList<String> stationList = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<Station> stationList = new ArrayList<Station>();

 private ListView stationName;
 private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;



 //Method for DOM Parser
  public void readXML(){

    try {

        //new xml file and Read
        File file1 = new File("src/fl_wx_index3.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(file1);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("station");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

                final Element first = (Element) node;

                station_id = first.getElementsByTagName("station_id").item(0).getTextContent();
                state = first.getElementsByTagName("state").item(0).getTextContent();
                station_name = first.getElementsByTagName("station_name").item(0).getTextContent();
                latitude = Double.parseDouble(first.getElementsByTagName("latitude").item(0).getTextContent());
                longitude = Double.parseDouble(first.getElementsByTagName("longitude").item(0).getTextContent());
                html_url = first.getElementsByTagName("html_url").item(0).getTextContent();

                //iterate thru list, returning names of each airport
                stationList.add(new Station(station_id, state, station_name, latitude, longitude, html_url));

            }

        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Initialize the UI components
    stationName = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    //object for method call to read XML document
        MainActivity activity1 = new MainActivity();
        activity1.readXML();

    //List to contain Weather station Names
     final ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

     for (int i = 0; i < stationList.size(); ++i) {
          nameList.add(stationList.get(i).getStationName());
        }

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList);

    // By using setAdapter method, you plugged the ListView with adapter
    stationName.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Here is a sample of XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wx_station_index>
    <credit>NOAA's National Weather Service</credit>
    <credit_URL>http://weather.gov/</credit_URL>
    <image>
            <url>http://weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif</url>
            <title>NOAA's National Weather Service</title>
            <link>http://weather.gov</link>
    </image>
    <suggested_pickup>08:00 EST</suggested_pickup>
    <suggested_pickup_period>1140</suggested_pickup_period>

<station>
    <station_id>NFNA</station_id>
    <state>FJ</state>
    <station_name>Nausori</station_name>
    <latitude>-18.05</latitude>
    <longitude>178.567</longitude>
    <html_url>http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/NFNA.html</html_url>
    <rss_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/NFNA.rss</rss_url>
    <xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/NFNA.xml</xml_url>
</station>

<station>
    <station_id>KCEW</station_id>
    <state>FL</state>
            <station_name>Crestview, Sikes Airport</station_name>
    <latitude>30.79</latitude>
    <longitude>-86.52</longitude>
            <html_url>http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/KCEW.html</html_url>
            <rss_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KCEW.rss</rss_url>
            <xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KCEW.xml</xml_url>
</station>
```

Activity main XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Why are you not using a `ListActity`? Maybe the problem is in your layout `activity_main.xml`,  post your xml.

You don't need to instantiate `MainActivity` to call `readXML()`, just call it from `onCreate()`.

Comment: I've posted my XML. I switched to ListActivity andI tried parsing XML from within OnCreate(). Now it just crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because of your OnCreate

Instead of

```
MainActivity activity1 = new MainActivity();
activity1.readXML();
```

you should really be calling just

```
readXML();
```

Comment: Changed. Now it displays nothing as before.

Comment: also, looking at your layout, your ListView1 has a margin of 115dp. Try taking that out or setting it to something much smaller, such as 5dp.

Comment: Finally realized the problem. All I had to was move the xml to the assets folder - then set as the build path. and then use use getAssets().

Answer (score 0):

First: take a deep breath and relax, you are not the only one (and that is a relief to myself too), I had the most frustration with ListViews, what you really need, is called a custom list adapter. It took me forever to figure out and finally thank God I have a decent handle on it.

1- As mentioned before, you don't want to be creating a new activity to call `readXML()` it is in the same class as your activity, therefore just call it.

2- Change `public ArrayList<Station> stationList = new ArrayList<Station>();` to `private List<Station> stationList = new ArrayList<Station>();`. No need to publicize it, and `List` is a better variable than `ArrayList()`.

3- can you post your 'main_activity.xml` file.

4- you stated that your parser works, so you are 100% that after calling `readXML()` the variable `stationList` contains all the values from your dataXML right?

Then let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the understanding. I posted main activity xml. and changed from array list to 'list'. The XML works when I test in a separate java test file, but I haven't been able to verify from an actual android activity.

Comment: remove the +'s from those two `android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"` and `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"`, you are adding the id three times, that should create an error, you can add an id only once. And then try to add this after calling `readXML()`: `Log.v("station name",stationList.get(0).getStationName()+"");`, and see if it prints a value in the LogCat.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work. removing the +'s had no affect and placing Log.v etc after readXML() resulted in a fatal error.

Comment: You realize what that means right? it means the adapter is empty. `readXML()` is not doing it's job, it is not populating `stationList`! In other words, "THAT IS YOUR TARGET TO ANALYSE" :)

Comment: Oh right forgot about, sorry the last few days. Yes, my list view works just fine now. Thanks for the follow up.

Comment: No problem, and if you could "check/approve" the response with the most help :)